# Из андроида отправить пароль открытым видом, а на хостинге хранить в закодированном виде

Tags: php, java, android, безопасность

Можно ли из андроида отправлять пароль открытым видом, а на хостинге  закодировать посредством php и хранить в базе данных?, так безопасно?

Comment: Если отправить через защищённый канал (HTTPS), то можно

Answer (score 2):

По порядку:

1. "Можно ли отправить?" - можно. "так безопасно?" - нет! Перехватить пароль по пути по типу MITM не составляет каких либо трудностей
2. Закодировать на хостинге? - Зачем тогда уже кодировать? Ну если только на всякий случай. Тут бы по хорошему сразу его кодировать или работать с токенами и так далее, про способы авторизации можно почитать и выбрать для себя приемлемый способ